# MariaDB Warning: 'root@localhost' has both ... The password will be ignored

Tags: mysql, passwords, warnings, mariadb, root

I have installed MariaDB on Ubuntu LTS 16.04. Then I have run

```
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

and set a root password. Accessing the DB via `mysql -u root -p` works fine. But checking the status with `service mysql status` opens a log file with this warning:

```
[Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' has both a password and an authentication plugin specified. The password will be ignored.
```

The questions are:

1. Is this a worry or completely normal?
2. If this is a worry, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is normal, if by saying *"accessing the DB via `mysql -u root -p` works fine"* you mean that you are running it while being a system root (or under `sudo`). You should not be able to do it as an ordinary user.

Packages generated by Ubuntu by default have [unix_socket](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/unix_socket-authentication-plugin) authentication for the local root. To check, run

```
SELECT user, host, plugin FROM mysql.user;
```

You should see `unix_socket` in the `plugin` column for `root@localhost`.

If you want to use the password authentication instead, run

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = '' WHERE plugin = 'unix_socket';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed reply (an sorry for not being able to upvote your answer)! That got rid of the warning. However, I now see `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` in the status log after MariaDB is restarted after a server reboot. Plus, restarting MariaDB via `service mysql restart`does not work anymore?!?

Comment: Ubuntu must have changed other scripts accordingly. The old way to start and monitor the service was having a special `debian-sys-maint` user with its own `debian.conf` which contained a generated password. To my understanding, one of reasons to start using `unix_socket` was to get rid of this rather awkward legacy. If you want to keep using the scripts, my usual advice is to keep `root@localhost` as Ubuntu wants it (with `unix_socket`), and additionally create another super user which you would set up with a password authentication and use for your purposes.